# MtGox socket.io streaming problem

Tags: mtgox, api, websockets

MtGox Streaming API is down or is something wrong with the code.

I used this example https:// bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/src/004c254993963baeb239ac7ac7f676b5024fc93f/socket/ws.client.html?at=master

You can see the example here http://atc.leadsoft.eu/test.html

I entered the server url (https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox) and click connect, but most of the time it writes only Connected or Connection timeout and freezes.

Comment: Please paste the code itself here.

Comment: You have the code in the first link .... https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/src/004c254993963baeb239ac7ac7f676b5024fc93f/socket/ws.client.html?at=master

Comment: You need the code here mate. Not a link. And you need to give us the actual few lines that is not working. Not 327 lines of code. This is if you want your question answered

Comment: I think this would be better posted on StackExchange. Mt. Gox is loosing lot's of customers right now, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Mtgox's api sucks. It's not your fault, its theirs. It's almost impossible to programmatically get a good reading of their order book. `socket.io` only works about 20% of the time and the `http` api often gives just wrong information.

To get around this I have several server instances constantly reconnecting an disconnecting until a successful steam is established and then it reports back to me until it fails. The idea is to always have at least one working stream.

I realize this can be incredibly impractical so you may want to use a service like [bitcoin charts](http://bitcoincharts.com/) which has their own api, but if you need data more then every 15 min you will either have to pay or come up with some round about solution.

[Here's](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=285578.0;topicseen) some other people complaining about the same thing. One suggests using `websockets` and claims that he's had more success.